# Convert a string to int in Java without allocating a String

Tags: java, string, integer, parseint

I have thousands of lines of text file, similar to this:

```
0000:0010:1111:3000
0003:0010:1113:3000
0004:0010:1188:3009
```

and so on, where the data is to be parsed as ints.

The most obvious way to do it is by using `Integer.parseInt(String)`. However, it needs a `String`, and since `String`s are immutable, we have to allocate again and again `String`s just to convert them to ints.

It is to be run in a mobile device where allocating a String and letting the GC run takes a considerable effort.

I am hoping to be able to have a method like `parseInt(char[] chars, int offset, int length)` so that we don't need to do allocations. Is that possible? Is there any implementation in standard Java/JDK/Android library that can already do that?

Comment: What makes you think allocating a `char[]` will be any more efficient than allocating a `String`? They're both objects.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish the whole file or line can be put into a single `char[]`, but we need multiple `String` objects to parse the values to integer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and call [`useDelimiter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29) to set your separator(s). Something like,

```
String str = "0000:0010:1111:3000\n" + "0003:0010:1113:3000\n"
        + "0004:0010:1188:3009";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
sc.useDelimiter("[:|\\s]+"); // <-- one or more colon or whitespace
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.printf("%04d%n", sc.nextInt()); // <-- format to 4 digits with
                                               //     leading zeros.
}
```

Comment: While this avoids the explicit String allocations, OP may want to do some performance testing of Scanner and using a regular expression.  My guess is that checking `if ((theChar < '0') || (theChar > '9')) ` (or similar) would be considerably faster.  Also, I wonder if `Scanner.nextInt()` etc... allocates a String internally - seems likely but I haven't checked the source code.

Comment: Addendum: [Scanner.hasNextInt()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/Scanner.java#Scanner.hasNextInt%28int%29) appears to create a new String, but you'd have to really follow the code to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple to parse int from char array, this is demo code:

```
public static int parseInt(char[] chars, int offset, int length) {
    int r = 0;
    for (int i = offset; i < offset + length; ++i) {
        r *= 10;
        r += chars[i] - '0';
    }

    return r;
}
```

You can add some security check for array length and make sure the char is really digits if you like.

Answer (score -1):

If you really care that much about performance, you'll have to write your own code to parse the ints.  e.g.

```
public static int parseInt(String s, int startPos, int len) {
  // code omitted, it would be simple
}
```

Where the String s is your entire file (or perhaps one line thereof). Search for end of lines and colons and get your numbers.  Or use a char[] as in your idea.  I don't know of a built in Java class to do this but the code is simple enough - something you learn in Java 1 at school.